# Accent above ligature

Tags: accents, ligatures

I want to typeset a text in *fracture*, using some accented characters. I am using the `yfonts` package and I have problems using accents over ligatures it defines. I find, however, that my issue also *affects normal ligatures* we are used to in TeX. Any way I try to add an accent, the ligature breaks apart. This MWE demonstrates my issue:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}

{fl} \v{fl}                 % Normal

\textfrak{{s:} \v{s:} š:}   % fracture with yfonts

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @campa You are right. I replaced `yfonts` with `oldgerm` -- it even has better documentation. You are also right this is unrelated, as the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put accents over two characters. The ligature `s:` is treated as two characters and the accent goes over the first.

You can directly use the slot:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oldgerm}

\begin{document}

\textfrak{{s:} \v{\symbol{141}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to get it? I printed a font table:

[image]

Comment: I was sort of taught (can't remember by whom) that `oldgerm` should be preferred over `yfonts` but  I found a 2003 contribution to the TeXnische Komödie which says quite the opposite. Do you have any idea what is best?

Comment: @campa I didn't investigate.